# LINQ tags in Stack Overflow

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There are a lot of LINQ tags in Stack Overflow: [linq](/questions/tagged/linq), [linq-to-objects](/questions/tagged/linq-to-objects), [linq-to-entities](/questions/tagged/linq-to-entities), [linq-to-xml](/questions/tagged/linq-to-xml) and a lot of crazy stuff. There one big tag that doesn't follow the more or less general pattern of `linq-to-`, and that is: [linqtosql](/questions/tagged/linqtosql). Are there any chances of getting that renamed to [linq-to-sql](/questions/tagged/linq-to-sql)? I know I could go and edit the 1300 or so questions myself, but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 1):

This goes hand in hand with the many suggestions to have some kind of tag editing tool. The biggest problem right now is that it is a lot of power to be giving users and they could do some pretty dangerous stuff to the database with it. Consistency is something we should definitely strive for when it comes to tags, however, so at the very least we could make topics like this and have them manually do it.

Answer (score -6):

I want all the linq-to-XXX tags changed to linqtoXXX.

Comment: No! That would break google searches matching the tag text.  Multiple words in tags need a separator, because they are often the only place those words are mentioned in the question.

Comment: great point by Joel

Comment: I was being facetious.

Comment: Which is probably why it got down voted.

Comment: NO!  SHOCK AND AWE.

Comment: The only shock I see, is that this answer doesn't have more down-votes.